# Default nginx conf file

Tags: nginx

Suppose I have 3 nginx conf files and default_server is not defined in any of them. Now if a request comes to the serve and If its value does not match any server name, or the request does not contain that header field, It will take which nginx config to serve the request.

I mean how is it prioritized?

Comment: first `server` section found will be used

Answer (score 1):

I guess, first vhost would be used. If you use including virtual hosts (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*) the hosts would be included in alphabetical order. So, if you have hosts "a", "b" and "c", first of them will be "a".

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at nginx documentation [Server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

> If no server_name is defined in a server block then nginx uses the
>   empty name as the server name.
>
> ```
> nginx versions up to 0.8.48 used the machine’s hostname as the 
> server name in this case
> ```